# Tensorflow not detecting GPU after correct cuda and toolkit

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu

In my venv:

tensorflow - 2.16.1

nvcc -V - Build cuda_12.3.r12.3

nvidia-smi shows gpu

```
python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"
2024-03-19 15:43:31.159215: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:210] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2024-03-19 15:43:31.778551: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
2024-03-19 15:43:32.622001: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_executor.cc:998] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2024-03-19 15:43:32.660742: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:2251] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
[]
```